# Make JavaFX Button visually appear to be clicked on right click

Tags: swing, javafx

I converted some old Java Swing code to JavaFX. The JavaFX code had explicit `doClick()` for the right mouse button calls:

```
myButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public final void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
            // ...
        }
        else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {
            // ...
            myButton.doClick();
        }
    }
});
```

Left clicks make the button visually appear to be clicked in Java Swing. However right clicks do not visually do this without adding `myButton.doClick()`

I am seeing the same visual behavior in JavaFX and I want right clicks to visually make the button look clicked. Below is my JavaFX code:

```
myButton.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(final MouseEvent event) {
        if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            // ...
        }
        else if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

What do I have to add to make right clicks visually click `myButton`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That visual appearance of button click is usually referred as "armed" pseudo state. So you can turn on/off the armed pseudo state of the button when doing right button pressed&released.
Something like..

```
myButton.setOnMousePressed(e->{
    if(e.getButton()== MouseButton.SECONDARY){
        myButton.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("armed"), true);
    }
});
myButton.setOnMouseReleased(e->{
    if(e.getButton()== MouseButton.SECONDARY){
        myButton.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("armed"), false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating the `:armed` pseudo class is not enough if you want the `Button`'s action to be fired by a right click. You actually need to arm the `Button`. In other words, you need to make the [`armed`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#armedProperty) property change to `true`. Also, updating the `armed` property will update the pseudo class for you.

As the `armed` property is read-only, you can't set it directly; you need to call [`arm()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#arm()) and [`disarm()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#disarm()). You may also need to manually call [`fire()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#fire()) (expanded on below). Here's an example:

```
Button button = new Button("Click Me!");
button.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Button clicked!"));
button.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
    if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
        button.arm();
    }
});
button.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
    if (button.isArmed()) {
        button.disarm();
        button.fire();
    }
});
```

However, you don't appear to need the `onMouseReleased` handler at all—at least in JavaFX 11 and 12, using the default `Button'`s skin/behavior. The `Button`'s behavior class will fire the action if said `Button` is armed at the time the mouse is released (and no keys are down). Note that the default behavior class does a more complex check regarding which `MouseButton` was used (i.e. it does more then just check `event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY`). You can see the implementation for yourself [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/blob/05606ebe4ab24bbe7f3530eeeeefd136d0ff6a53/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/behavior/ButtonBehavior.java#L178).

All that said, if you only want the visuals to change then you should use the approach shown in [Sai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55642907/6395627).